# How can I remove lines in html2pdf output caused by rowspan in table?

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

I have table that uses `rowspan` and `colspan` for converting/exporting to PDF. The `colspan` mostly works, but I have an issue with `rowspan` that have a line between `<td>` while exporting.

What should I change in the code to remove lines as below?

[image: line html2pdf rowspan]

```html
<tr>
  <td style="letter-spacing:0.2px;font-size: 10px;" width="10%" rowspan="2" class="p-2 text-center fw-bold"> Test </td>
  <td style="letter-spacing:0.2px;font-size: 10px;" width="10%" colspan="2" class="p-2 text-center fw-bold">yes / no</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="letter-spacing:0.2px;font-size: 10px;" class="p-2 text-center fw-bold">Yes</td>
  <td style="letter-spacing:0.2px;font-size: 10px;" class="p-2 text-center fw-bold">No</td>
</tr>
```

```js
var opt = {
  margin: [30, 10],
  filename: 'exported.pdf',
  image: {
    type: 'jpeg',
    quality: 0.98
  },
  html2canvas: {
    scale: 2,
    scrollX: 0,
    scrollY: 0,
    useCORS: true,
    dpi: 96,
    letterRendering: true
  },
  jsPDF: {
    unit: 'mm',
    format: 'a4',
    orientation: 'portrait'
  },
  pagebreak: {
    mode: ['avoid-all'],
  }
};
```

Comment: You can apply CSS styling to the table to remove borders between cells. You can set the `border-collapse` property to collapse and then apply specific border styles to the cells as needed. Have you tried it ?

Comment: ya, i just try to add CSS styling to the table : border-collapse: collapse;
and the cells : border: 1px solid black;
but still have a line in middle of rowspan